# Returning Incremented Numbers in Java

Tags: java, return, increment

I am trying to solve this "incrementation" problem in a Java code but I can't find myself arriving at a solution:

```
public class Return {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = returnn(3);
    System.out.println(n);
   }

   public static int returnn(int n) {
    return n++;
   }
}
```

I am supposed to return 4 but it is returning 3 instead. Why is that? Also, when I type:
`return n+=1`it works. This is confusing me. Also, what is the difference between `n++` and `++n`? Any clarification is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see the bottom section of [the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) on the increment operators.

Comment: ++n will worj but be warned : the value of n in the function if a copy of the value in main. So return (n+1) will have same effect as the location param n in function returnn is lost once the function returns

Comment: Just `return n+1;` There is no need to increment the local variable.

Comment: you are using postincrement.  3 is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You have to write `return ++n` because `return n++` evaluates to the original value of `n`, and `++n` evaluates to the value of `n` after being incremented.

Comment: Or just (n + 1) as anyway the parameter n value is lost once the function returns. So ++n has no long lasting affect here

Comment: Why would I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following;

```
public class Return {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = returnn(3);
        System.out.println(n);
    }

    public static int returnn(int n) {
        return ++n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`n++` increments `n` by 1 AFTER evaluating `n`'s current value

`++n` increments `n` by 1 and then evaluates its value

Your method `returnn(int)` should return `++n`, instead of `n++`.